# Approval Task Workfow 2013

Tags: workflow, tasks, approval

I have a 2010 Approval Task Workflow. When an item on my list is created, an approval task is created. With the standard approval workflow 2010, when the task is created, it is accessible inside the workflow itself.

I have to rewrite it into a 2013 workflow, where the OOB Approval Workflow seems not to be available, since 2010. The solution I found is [this](http://aspetraining.com/resources/blog/how-to-create-an-approval-workflow-sharepoint-2013) one.
The problem is that in this case we have no access to the created task, we only get a TaskID/Guid (see .21 of link).

What exactly is this ID?
Is there a way to access the created task inside this workflow once the task has been approved or denied?

Answer (score 2):

**What exactly is this ID?**

The `TaskID` is the ID of the newly created (assigned) task in the same step. it's by design assigned to a variable called TaskID.

**Is there a way to access the created task inside this workflow once the task has been approved or denied?**

Depends on your permission, you can check the `Workflow Tasks` in the `associated task list` for your workflow.

> **Note:** You need a contribute permission on a Workflow task list to can approve or reject the assigned tasks.

**To open the associated task list, do the following:**

- Open Workflow via SharePoint Designer.
- In its settings, below customization, Click open the task list.
- From the above ribbon, click on preview in browser option.

[image]

Comment: I'm sorry, but the returned TaskId is not the ID of the new created task. All SharePoint ids are numeric (an integer), the TaskId is a guid instead. I inspected both items using powershell and I can't find a match with this Guid.

Comment: The Task GUID field contains the generated unique identification codes for each task, but the Task ID is an incremental generated  number for each Task, you can show it by modifying your view ,Also you can log the value of the Task ID to make sure it's not the Task Guid :) Please don;t hesitate to inform me in case you have further information

Comment: Indeed, when I log the outputted TaskId i get `440E4FAA-3A98-46F7-BF20-73F088D3C73C`

Answer (score 0):

I found out that the returned TaskId indeed IS the identifier of the new created element, but not the ID, it is the GUID.

I did't know that each SharePonint element has also a unique Guid which allows to lookup an element as the ID does.